# A promise is created but not returned from it

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bookshelf.js

I am trying to wrap my head around this... but I'm getting this warning no matter where I put return...

> Warning: a promise was created in a handler at home/app/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7 but was not returned from it
>   server     |     at ._doFetch (/home/app/server/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/method.js:13:13)

```
module.exports = {
    getUser: (req, res) => {
        var found_user = User.query({where: {email: req.body.email}, orWhere: {username: req.body.email}}).fetch()

        found_user.then(user => {
            if (user) {
                res.status(200).json(user)
            } else {
                res.status(422).json(new error.ERROR_422("No user found under username/email"));
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
            res.status(500).json(new error.ERROR_500(err));
        })

    }
```

I'm using Bookshelf.js, What am I supposed to return here?

Comment: Try using `return found_user.then...`

Comment: What is giving you the error? I assure you, there is nothing wrong with what you are doing here. Is there perhaps an overzealous eslint file somewhere?

Comment: @GeorgeMauer That's why I am frustrated, I mean, they are all warnings not errors, the code runs fine, just idk where I am getting this

Comment: Right, so where are you seeing that and when? In your console during runtime? In your text editor when you save the file? In a build process? There's something about our development environment that is doing this but we have no way to guess it unfortunately.

Comment: Maybe use `Promise.resolve();`?

Comment: What is `doFetch`?

Answer (score 1):

You must return the promise from your exported method, so the promise can be handled outside. Try changing it to something like

```
module.exports = {
  getUser: (req, res) => {
    var found_user = User.query({where: {email: req.body.email}, orWhere: {username: req.body.email}}).fetch()

    found_user.then(user => {
      if (user) {
        res.status(200).json(user)
      } else {
        res.status(422).json(new error.ERROR_422("No user found under username/email"));
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
        res.status(500).json(new error.ERROR_500(err));
    })

    return found_user // <<<--- Add this
  }
```